# How to calculate average of a column associated if specific text matches in other column using formula in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

[image]

I want to calculate the average of passes (C6) made by defenders (C3) and using `=AVERAGEIF(F2:F598,"def",C2:C596)`
But its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`=AVERAGEIF(C2:C598,"def*",F2:F598)`

Comment: @ShayThan Great! Would you mind selecting this as the answer?